# How hadoop read all data and then splits in chunks?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, jobs

i am using hadoop 2.6 for processing enough data, so i have a question about how hadoop read all data and then splits in chunks?. I understand that first upload data to hdfs, then data is splits in N chunks depends of the size of the chunk. In the case that i have 1TB of text for do wordcount algorithm, i suppose that hadoop first raise memory the file, read file and and somehow read for a x row then copy data that in chunk.

If my assumption is bad, how is the correct way, because i think raise data to memory, this should be done in pieces. As you do internally?

Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your data upload to HDFS statement is correct.

When the **WordCount** `MapReduce` job will be launched, for each chuck (block) one `Mapper` task get assigned and executed. The output of the `Mappers` is sent to `Reducers` after the `sort-shuffle` phase. During sort-shuffle, Mapper output are `partitioned`, `sorted` and `received (copied) by the Reducers`.

The `MapReduce` framework does not read any data and copy into any chuck. That is already done, when you stored the file in HDFS.

Comment: i guess, i should to explain better my question, i understand about MapReduce framework, my question is focused  How hadoop segments all data?

Comment: @WilD what do you mean by `How hadoop segments all data?`

Comment: More clearly, i want to know how hdfs segmented and reads all data. Because i think when hdfs partitions all data in chunks in one moment hdfs  should reads all data for know that this partitioning  for that doesn't exist data corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

When You upload the data based on your block size, you data is divided in to blocks and stored on different nodes.

But when you launch map-reduce jobs, 
We should know about splits.
Its not the block no = mapper no

its no of splits = number of mappers

splits are logical division and block is physical division.
data is read in splits. by default split size = block size but we can change this.